# How to change the view value on input without modifying the model value in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

In an input field, when user types something, I need it to presented "$" for each character he types. But the actual value should remain same.

**For example,**
If the user types "Surendher"

He should see "$$$$$$$$$" in input field

The model value should remain "Surendher"

Please advise me on this.

Comment: Do you need to hide a password or it is for something different ?

Comment: @QuentinFonck - Yes, I need to hide my password without setting input type="password". The existing workaround in stack overflow are 1.Applying style  -webkit-text-security: disc; 2. Setting dotfont as font family for the input field. These I don't like.

Comment: Why not use input type="password" for password?

Comment: @Sprep - If i use input type="password", browser will start asking "Would you like to save this credential" which I don't need

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but this is NOT GOOD, BUGS! Better to use css / type='password'.

```js
let realValue = '';
const str =Array(100).fill('$').join('');

changed = (value) => {
  if(value.length > realValue.length) {
    const target = value.slice(-1);
    realValue += target;
    this.displayValue = str(0, value.length)
  }
}
```

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="displayValue" #input (keyup)="changed(input.value)">
```